# Ubuntu 16.04: black screen after suspend

Tags: 16.04, suspend

Since I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04, the suspend mode gives me trouble. Every time I resume from suspend, the screen won't work and I must hard reboot to fix the problem.

I already tried two solutions I found on the net:

- using `xbindkeys` with the command `xrandr --auto`
- saving an executable file in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` with the following code:

  ```
  case $(1) in
      thaw|resume)
          sleep 5
          sudo -u lolc env DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xrandr --auto
          ;;
      *)  ;;
  esac
  ```

What else can I try? This bug is really bothering me!

Comment: I've the same pb on both my computers, one with intel GPU (displayport) and the other with Nvidia proprietary driver (hdmi), since the last kernel update I think. I hope we'll find a solution. I've tried `xrandr --auto` with no success.